# Writing a file from byte array into a zip file

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to write a file name "content" from a byte array into an existing zip file.

I have managed so far to write a text file \  add a specific file into the same zip.
What I'm trying to do, is the same thing, only instead of a file, a byte array that represents a file. I'm writing this program so it will be able to run on a server, so I can't create a physical file somewhere and add it to the zip, it all must happen in the memory.

This is my code so far without the "writing byte array to file"  part.

```
public static void test(File zip, byte[] toAdd) throws IOException {

    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "true");
    Path path = Paths.get(zip.getPath());
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {

        Path nf = fs.getPath("avlxdoc/content");
         try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(nf, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
             //write file from byte[] to the folder
            }


    }
}
```

(I tried using the BufferedWriter but it didn't seem to work...)

Thanks!

Comment: Since that should be in memory, have you considered using [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `BufferedWriter` to write binary content! A `Writer` is made to write *text* content.

Use that instead:

```
final Path zip = file.toPath();

final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();
final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zip.toUri());

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
)  {
    Files.write(zipfs.getPath("into/zip"), buf,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

(note: `APPEND` is a guess here; it looks from your question that you want to append if the file already exists; by default the contents will be overwritten)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me lots of time figuring that out. most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ZipOutputStream to access the zipped file.

ZipOutputStream lets you add an entry to the archive from whatever you want, specifying the name of the entry and the bytes of the content.

Provided you have a variable named `theByteArray` here is a snippet to add an entry to an zip file:

```
ZipOutputStream zos =  new ZipOutputStream(/* either the destination file stream or a byte array stream */);
/* optional commands to seek the end of the archive */
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("filename_into_the_archive"));
zos.write(theByteArray);
zos.closeEntry();
try {
    //close and flush the zip
    zos.finish();
    zos.flush();
    zos.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    //handle exceptions
}
```

Comment: Why, since with Java 7+ you can access zip files as filesystems, as the OP does and as my answer also does?

Comment: Uh, I was not aware of that functionality. Let me upvote your answer, it is indeed more elegant ;) edit: insufficient reputation point for upvoting...sorry :(

Comment: Can somebody upvote @fge 's answer? I don't have enough reputation points to do that.